# Xcode 8 and exportPath

Tags: ios, xcode, teamcity, xcode8, xcodebuild

Starting with Xcode 8, my TeamCity builds no longer create an Artifact with the proper name.  Here is my command line to export archive:

```
xcodebuild -project "${XCODE_PROJECT}" -exportArchive \
       -archivePath "${ARTIFACT_DIR}${ARTIFACT_NAME}.xcarchive" \
       -exportPath "${ARTIFACT_DIR}${ARTIFACT_NAME}.ipa" \
       -exportOptionsPlist ./export-appstore.plist
```

If ARTIFACT_DIR and ARTIFACT_NAME result in "/builds/myApp-1.0.1.ipa", for example, xcodebuild will actually create "/builds/myApp-1.0.1.ipa/myApp.ipa".

The "man" documentation for '-exportPath' says "Specifies the destination for the exported product, including the name of the exported file".  But clearly it's assuming the file name from the Xcode project and using the entire parameter just for the path.

Is this a known bug that will be fixed, or did they remove functionality with this latest version of Xcode?

Comment: Anyone else deal with this yet?